# Show that if $P$ is an invertible $m$ x $m$ matrix, then$rank(PA)=rank(A)$, then show if $Q$ is invertible, then rank $AQ$= rank $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, solution-verification

Did I show this properly? Any mistakes, any steps left out? Thank you.
$$$$

Show that if $P$ is an invertible $m$ x $m$ matrix, then$rank(PA)=rank(A)$.

solution:

$col(PA)=PA$**x**

$col(PA)=P(A$**x**$)$

$col(A)⊆col(PA)$

$rank(A)≤rank(PA)$

$nul(PA)=$**x** such that $PA$**x**$=0$

$nul(PA)=$**x** such that $P(A$**x**$)=0$

$nul(A)⊆nul(PA)$

$n-rank(A)≤n-rank(PA)$

$rank(PA)≤rank(A)$

$rank(PA)=rank(A)$

Part two: Now, use the above exercise to show that: if $Q$ is invertible, then rank $AQ$= rank $A$

From the above, we know that $rank(Q^TA^T)=rank(A^T)$.

$rank(Q^TA^T)=rank((AQ)^T)=rank(AQ)$

$rank(A^T)=rank(A)$

so, rank $AQ$= rank $A$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ is full-column rank matrix, then is rank($AB$) = rank ($BA$) = rank($B$)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/745071/if-a-in-mathbbcm-times-n-is-full-column-rank-matrix-then-is-rankab)

Comment: Is $X\in\Bbb F^n$?  Second, $\operatorname{col(PA)}=\{v\in\Bbb F^n\mid v=APX\}$, as you wrote, $APX=\operatorname{col}(AP)$ is meaningless unless $X=0$, because a non-trivial subspace doesn't have one single element.

Comment: x is an arbitrary vector in R^n representing all possible weights that can  be used to form a linear combination of the columns of PA, which is exactly what the column space is.

Comment: are you saying that my failure to use the set notation makes the statement meaningless?

Comment: Yes,  that part is meaningless because you haven't even mentioned what $x$ is. I just assumed what it meant and then saw what you wrote about the kernel and realized what you probably wanted to say. Keep in mind you have to write everything down on the exam. Good luck! (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the rank theorem it suffices to show $\dim(\ker(\mathbf A))=\dim(\ker(\mathbf{PA}))=\dim(\ker(\mathbf {AP}))$. $$\ker(\mathbf{PA})=\{\mathbf x:\mathbf 0=\mathbf{PA}(\mathbf x)=\mathbf P(\mathbf {Ax})\}=\{\mathbf x:\mathbf{A}(\mathbf x)=\mathbf 0\}=\ker(\mathbf A)$$ $$\therefore \dim(\ker(\mathbf {PA}))=\dim(\ker(\mathbf A))$$  Finally, because $\mathbf P^T$ is invertible and the row and column space of $\mathbf{AP}$ have the same dimension then $$\dim(\ker(\mathbf{AP}))=\dim(\ker(\mathbf{P}^T\mathbf{A}^T))=\dim(\ker(\mathbf A^T))=\dim(\ker(\mathbf A))$$ where $^T$ denotes matrix transposition.